# Text is getting cut off in android for react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, text

I am working on React native and I am new to this. I am trying to display text, But, It's showing in an android end of the text ... and not showing complete text. It's only happening in android, working fine in iOS.

I have written following code

```
<Text
  numberOfLines={1}
  adjustsFontSizeToFit
  minimumFontScale={0.1}
  style={labelStyle} //labelStyle nothing I have written
></Text>
```

Can anyone suggest me, where I am doing wrong in the code?

[image]

Comment: please share some more code like parent view or etc.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This usually happens when you have this: `fontWeight:bold` and your android device is for example a Oneplus or Oppo (there are some other brands tho), it's a conflict with your system font. 
To fix, you can add some other `fontFamily` or put 2 blank spaces in front of the word seems to work too.
See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114

**Edit**

Setting `textBreakStrategy` to `simple` on the Text element also seems to work for some devices like Samsung galaxy s10, Google Pixel

Comment: this is really interesting. it's only been happening on my one plus and bugging me for days now. thanks for the pointer!

Comment: This solved the problem for OnePlus and Samsung devices. Thanks.

Comment: Clever. Why I coundn't think about the blank text?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who found provided solutions not working like in my case
here's my solution to text being cut on OnePlus phones:

just set  component style with these properties

```
alignSelf: 'stretch',
textAlign: 'center',
```

this is probably an equivalent to android match_parent setting. 
Did not test how it will affect iOS though as I don't have that possibility right now.

Answer (score 5):

I'd had problem of text cut horizontally.
by using `lineHeight` to text components, and boom, my problem solved

Comment: Thank you!  I totally forgot about lineHeight :)

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with it for a long time, I finally figured it out.

Seems like for default, the Text sets the property  **textBreakStrategy** to * highQuality*.

Changing it to * simple* solved my problem.

Link here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.56/text#textbreakstrategy

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `flex: x` style to the `<View>` surrounding the `<Text>` element being cut worked for me, when using a OnePlus 7T.

Comment: flex:1 worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case adding fontFamily: 'arial' to the text component did the trick. Even fontFamily: 'abc' also works. I think it just requires fontFamily to be set.

Answer (score 1):

Adding extra space or adding textBreakStrategy as "simple" did not work for me.

I added `alignSelf:"stretch"` for the Text component style and it worked for me finally. If you want to text to be in the center just add `textAlign: "center"` as well.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I simply added padding and the issue resolved

if text cut off from the left side just add `paddingLeft:10`

in my case text was cut-off from top-side, when I was increasing the font size, so I added `paddingTop:20`

if text cut off from top
add `textAlignVertical: 'bottom'`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `numberOfLines` it will display correctly. If it still doesn't show up, it could be that the parent view has a fixed height (or maxHeight)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the last line of our paragraphs were getting cut off due to `'highQuality'` value of `textBreakStrategy` parameter. We changed this to `'simple'` and now all of our text displays. Apparently `highQuality` is actually low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding extra space at the end which is **not a good workaround**.

**Recommended:** Include default font-family in your application and it works same for all devices

Answer (score 0):

There are other better ways to fix this issue. but in my case adding `custom font` fixed the Text-cut issue and font alignment in different devices.

Adding Custom Font can easily solve the problem.

How to add custom fonts = [checkout this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825276/how-to-add-custom-font-in-react-native-android)

[react-native official docs on custom fonts](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/?redirected)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

1. remove fontWight : bold
2. add style in Text tag like this = width:'100%' (according to your text size)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with it not working completely on android devices. The problem was that I've set a **height** style property. It works well when I deleted it and moved some style properties to a wrapper.