# the font family for react native picker is not working

Tags: react-native, picker, font-family

```
<Picker itemStyle={{backgroundColor: "red",fontFamily:'ArbFONTS-GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT',}} >
 <Picker.Item fontFamily="ArbFONTS-GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT" label={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} value={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} />
 <Picker.Item label={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} value={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} />
</Picker>
```

Comment: in case you using `Picker` from `react-native`, the main `<Picker>` component receive `style` prop and not `itemStyle`

Comment: nope i am using picker "import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41827668/14027587 hope this will help you thanks