# Is it possible to implement Roboto Medium-500 weight font building an application using UI Kitten + React Native?

Tags: react-native, fonts, react-native-ui-kitten

I've been told by developer that only Regular 400 and Bold 700 can be implemented. Can someone please confirm this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815234/how-to-add-fonts-for-different-font-weights-for-react-native-android-project/70247374#70247374 this answer may help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

#### Step 1. Install the font

The fastest way will be using `expo-font` and `@expo-google-fonts/inter`

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/

BUT double-check on real devices because sometimes there are bugs like the [famous 2 last characters trimmed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114)

#### Step 2. Update `app-mapping-theme.json`

Update your [`ApplicationProvider` `customMapping` props](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/design-system/customize-mapping#merge-mappings)

```json
// app-mapping-theme.json
{
  "strict": {
    "text-font-family": "roboto"
  }
}
```

I imported the file on my `App.js` like this

```js
import { default as mapping } from "~/constants/app-mapping-theme.json";
```