# 'react-native-render-html' can't change font family for <strong> tag

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

I'm using react-native-render-html 6.3.4, attempting to use custom font, but can't seem to change the font family for 'strong' and 'em' tags. Other attributes are working like font size or font style but not font family.

````
        const html = `<p><strong> Custom font bold.</strong> Regular text font family. </p>`;

        <HTML
          source={{ html }}
          systemFonts={systemFonts}
          tagsStyles={{
            strong: {
              fontFamily: 'PLEC-Regular',
              fontStyle: 'italic',
              fontSize: 30,
            },
          }}
        />```
````

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815234/how-to-add-fonts-for-different-font-weights-for-react-native-android-project/70247374#70247374

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add fonts for different font weights for react-native android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815234/how-to-add-fonts-for-different-font-weights-for-react-native-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem. I don't know why but the `fontWeight` must be different `'700'`

```js
<HTML
          source={{ html }}
          systemFonts={systemFonts}
          tagsStyles={{
            strong: {
              fontFamily: 'PLEC-Regular',
              fontStyle: 'italic',
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight:'800',
            },
          }}
        />
```