Expo doesn't render italic fonts on Android
We are having 2 problems loading custom fonts on Android.

None of the italic versions work
The black version only works with weight 950, which is not an allowed value.


This is using:
"expo": "~51.0.8",
"expo-font": "~12.0.5",

On app.json:
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-font",
    {
      "fonts": [
        "./assets/fonts/Averta-Regular.otf",
        "./assets/fonts/Averta-RegularItalic.otf",
        "./assets/fonts/Averta-Semibold.otf",
        "./assets/fonts/Averta-SemiboldItalic.otf",
        "./assets/fonts/Averta-Black.otf",
        "./assets/fonts/Averta-BlackItalic.otf"
      ]
    }
  ]
],

And then part of the code is:
<Text
  style={{ fontFamily: "Averta-Black", fontWeight: 950, fontSize: 32 }}
>
  Averta Black 950
</Text>

<Text
  style={{
    fontFamily: "Averta-SemiboldItalic",
    fontWeight: 600,
    fontSize: 32,
    fontStyle: "italic",
  }}
>
  Averta Semibold Italic 600
</Text>

There are no errors or warnings on the console, and yet the fonts don't work as expected.
Any advice on what we can try?

More of a side note: I would look for a supported font. Fonts are complicated and in researching different questions regarding Changing Android system fonts and How do I fix monospace fonts once and for all? lead me down a rabbit hole about how complicated fonts are.

Thanks to all this issue
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42116
We figured out the fontWeight and fontStyle were causing the rendering errors.
Instead we use the full specific fontFamily, without the fontWeight and fontStyle.
The example code becomes:
<Text
  style={{ fontFamily: "Averta-Black", fontSize: 32 }}
>
  Averta Black 950
</Text>

<Text
  style={{
    fontFamily: "Averta-SemiboldItalic",
    fontSize: 32,
  }}
>
  Averta Semibold Italic 600
</Text>

For our real app we used an approach similar to the one explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55717885/3695939
