# Can not resolve symbol R and build.gradle error

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-2.2-froyo

I began to program with android and so I downloaded Android Studio 2.1.3 and android SDK and jdk 1.8.0_60 the Gradle version is 2.14.1.
I want to program with Android 2.2.
In my class called GameView is the problem:

`bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`

***it can not resolve symbol R***

I read that I can solve the problem in these ways:

`BUILD -> Clean Project`

`Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Nothing helped so I tried to changed the Versions in build.gradle(Module: app).
I do not really know wich Versions I need to program for Android 2.2.
Please help me or do you know any other solution to fix that problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: build --> rebuid project

Comment: Did you `import com.example.exampleapp.R`?

Comment: That also don't work

Comment: You may also need to restart Android Studio, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18183656/781729

Comment: Also a restart doesn't help - I tried that often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the solution was to put the **minSdkVersion from 8 to 9**.

I also changed the versions in build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.panjutorials.lazypudding"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

The only disadvantage is that I program with *Android Nougat* now but that's okay.

Good luck for everybody who has a similar problem.