# Android Studio: Why won't the options menu embedded on layout show on my emulator/preview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-optionsmenu

Error says:

> This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.
>   The following classes could not be found: item and menu

[image: img1]

And why is the java class for that layout is showing plenty of "Cannot resolve symbol R"?

[image: img2]

I'm not sure why the xml file and java class are not compiling. I appreciate any feedback from you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** have a layout of a menu inside the layout of an activity. It must be defined separately in an XML file inside the `res/menu/` directory, in a similar way as your `main_options_menu.xml` file is defined.

The reason for getting the `cannot resolve symbol R` error is because the Gradle build did not complete (due to an error). To fix it, either *build* or *clean* the project after removing all errors. You may check out ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio).