# Cannot resolve R.layout.splash on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos, android-layout, android-studio

```
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
}
```

Cannot display logout button after Facebook login, then I added these code from Facebook developer website source code, after that appear this "R.layout.splash" error, who can help me solve, thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Comment: clean the project first. Check you import. and if possible, first remove your already imported `R` and again import it

Comment: @PavneetSingh Hi. Cannot resolve symbol R meant include "R.layout.splash" error?

Comment: @AMANSINGH Hello, actually I can get Facebook login function in login activity, but no display Facebook logout button after login Facebook. And then I clean my project and rebuild again, still can't resolve it.

Comment: if clean did help then it mean there is something wrong with resources like they are misplaced , missing , wrong naming convention used  or it could be something wrong with fb dependency etc so have to look for every possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create an xml file for your missing layout resource.

Comment: Great, it's work , but I don't know why still got error in my source code.

Comment: can't except this type of error!!! anyway @KentChong whats your error now?

Comment: @AMANSINGH Hi, the error I solved yesterday after get answer from aznelite89. Anyway, thanks a lot.