# Why am I getting a 'cannot resolve symbol' error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop, gradle

I cannot see why I'm getting this error?  I'm certain my Gradle file and java class are up to par. Class and gradle file posted below.  Also, I have no errors in my XML files.

What I have done already:

File > Invalid Caches/Restart

Build > Clean Project

Build > Rebuild Project
Restart computer

These are the things that were suggested to do throughout the web but none of them worked.

SplashActivity.java

```
package com.apress.gerber.currencies;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 // Letter "R" is red 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash2); 
   }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
       compileSdkVersion 25
       buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
       useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' // newly added
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apress.gerber.currencies"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
     }
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// newly added
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
// newly added
provided 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:<version number>'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Your question would be answerable if you told us exactly what symbol could not be resolved. Please copy and paste the text of whatever error message you are seeing.

Comment: @KenY-N I wrote down what symbols cannot be resolved as comments if you check my java class again :)

Comment: You haven't imported either of the two values you say are red

Comment: @quicklearner There aren't any log messages.  The only thing that's happening is the words that have been indicated as comments in my java class are the symbols that cannot be resolved, these symbols are red.

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh ok.  How do I import them?

Comment: You should let Android Studio do it. I believe Alt + Enter opens the quick fix window

Comment: Alternatively, open up MainActivity and look at those imports

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok I pressed Alt + Enter & now the word Window isn't red in Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE anymore.  Now the only thing that's left that's red is the `R` letter.

Comment: Most of the times this error is because of problems in XML. did you compile your app?

Comment: @drulabs I tried compiling it but it didn't let me.  I'm assuming it didn't let me because I cannot resolve the `R` symbol (it's red).

Comment: perform a project cleanup

Comment: @drulabs If you check my original post, I've indicated that I've done that already :)

Answer (score 0):

Import those classes

```
import android.view.Window;
import com.apress.gerber.currencies.R;
```

If the `R` still cannot resolve, then you do have an error within your resources, not just the XML.

Lots of answers here ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Comment: My `R` is still red for some reason :0

Comment: My edit explains why. It's hard to help with that without seeing all the resources you have, and their contents.

Comment: I've seen that link before, it was no help for my case.

Comment: I'm so lost with this, I've been stuck on this problem for way too long.  It's preventing me from moving forward, I can't even run my app :(

Comment: Yeah it did, actually.

Comment: Okay, then either your Manifest or `R.layout.activity_splash2` got messed up