# on new project start, android studio cannot resolve symbol R, after rebuild/clean shows 2 errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

When I installed android studio, on the first start, there was an error about java jdk path. When I changed the path to the right folder and gradle runs automaticlly, it doesnt finish, but outputs 2 errors.
When I run the app or anything else that runs the gradle, the gradle then runs forever.

Also, in main_activity.java the R is red and popus says that they cannot resolve symbol.

Anybody knows what might be the problem?
Thank you in advance

Here is the log

```
    Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources,    :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

    Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
    Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
    :clean UP-TO-DATE
    :app:clean
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
     :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2510Library
     :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72510Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2510Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2510Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2510Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2510Library
     :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2510Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42510Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2510Library
     :app:prepareDebugDependencies
     :app:compileDebugAidl
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
    :app:generateDebugResValues
    :app:generateDebugResources
    :app:mergeDebugResources
    AAPT err(Facade for 32736313): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 6096667): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 25919441): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
     AAPT err(Facade for 16944395): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 23419837): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 2746010): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 1027071): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 15859919): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 2610883): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 22953243): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 13442010): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 27206966): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 9136167): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 18841131): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 3468898): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 9752414): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 30903940): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 7535420): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 15001831): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    AAPT err(Facade for 257390): /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/matej/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error:  Unterminated quoted string

    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
     Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

    Thread(png-cruncher_6): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_5): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

    hread(png-cruncher_3): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_4): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

    Thread(png-cruncher_11): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_18): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
    Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

    Thread(png-cruncher_1): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_7): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_2): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_12): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_9): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_10): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_20): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_15): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_8): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at  com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_13): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_19): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_16): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_17): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Thread(png-cruncher_14): Stream closed
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or     --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 33.35 secs
```

Comment: what version of gradle are you using?

Comment: @Manza I use 2.2.2, because I saw that 2.2.3 has the same problem

Comment: sorry, I misunderstod you, I'm using 2.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering how to do it, this is the solution

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhj3MY4SpHY

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Ubuntu  expert. However, you can try either one of the following: (hope it helps!)

1. **Clean the project and Sync Project with Gradle.**
2. **Please also check your xml files (this can be the main cause of problem)....may be something was falsely updated?**

Regards

Comment: Did the Sync Project with Gradle, it's gradeling forever, it also happens when I try to sync

What should I look for in these xml-s, I've looked them a few times, nothing seems strange

Thank you

Comment: Hi, if the gradeling process is taking a lot of time then the problem might be that your android studio has a proxy server setting. Try to disable it and work offline :  In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

It will reduce 90% gradle build time.   If this does not work then try to update your sdk tools! else try to restart your android studio.

Comment: synced it, error remains, cleand it, the gradle is still running, so I belive it's something else
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Checked the proxy, no proxy is checked in my settings, should it be auto-detect?

Comment: Did all you said, still running forever

Comment: Did you try to update your SDK tools? did you try "Offline work" option and then restarting the studio?  If these options dont work...please have a look at this post and try all the options in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio

Comment: upon installation, the SDK gave me a message that it is up to date, I've tried restarting it, the stopping gradle lasted forever, so I had to shut it down and run again, but I had the same problem. I've checked offline work, but havent run it while offline. I'll do that next and look at the link you sent me

Comment: Tried offline, still the same problems
Thank you fo your effort, I'll see the link you gave me and try with it

Comment: Your welcome! out of curiosity: what did work for you?

Comment: just posted the link of the video in responses, take a look. I belive that the thing is that, because I'm using 32 bit ubuntu, I needed to instal build version 23, but leave 25, becase there is probablly something in that version 25 that causes android studio errors if missing (I'm not certain about this, but it's the only logical explanation and since I've tried almost everything else and haven't found a solution, it might be true).
Video saved me, if you run on anyone with my problem, share it, please, the author of the video deserved it :)