# Resources tag error in Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol "

Tags: android-studio, resources

[image]

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="button_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">43dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FDFDFE</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Why am I getting red symbol at resources tag in Android Studio?

this image it saying cannot resolve symbol "

this is coming everywhere when there is need of resources tag it showing it

Comment: Could you maybe take a screenshot of the full error or add more context?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, activate your windows ;) . & you forgot the first resources tag from the code example. I think your question already answered here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio/32119880)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Custom Theme without selecting *parent* in Base theme. You can do this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MyCustomTheme">


</style>
<style name="MyCustomTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:textColor">#FDFDFE</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>

</style>
```