# I use Android for first time but when i open file .java i have the error in the picture below

Tags: java

I use android for first time but when i open file .java i have the error in the picture below

[image]

Comment: please aide me ,thnks for advance

Comment: please visit [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing R as an object but you have not created that object.

["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Comment: I edited my answer. You can find the answer in Stack Overflow already