# How to resolve "cannot resolve symbol error"?

Tags: android

```
package project.judil.com.demo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    LottieAnimationView animationView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
    animationView.setAnimation("muzli.json");
    animationView.loop(true);
    animationView.playAnimation();
}
```

Comment: Move animationView to Oncreate

Comment: [Lots of answers here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cannot+resolve+symbol+error+android).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move that entire **animationView** 
 inside **onCreate()** after **setContentView()**