# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' & Build errors

Tags: android, android-studio

In every project I'm getting same following error

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>   Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>   Information:BUILD FAILED

Even if I'm creating new project, without adding anything I'm getting above error, also getting an

> Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

in every project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Comment: make sure you are using png file in you project.

Answer (score 0):

Please check any resource file is missing or not.

Otherwise go to `Build` in the top menu and click on `Clean Project`.

If this also not works then restart `Android Studio`.

Comment: You did not get any option to import R in the code? Please hover on the error.

Comment: It's giving me the option for adding class, enum or something in my code with variable 'R'

Comment: It's not giving you the option Import Class?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error comes due to the path of the project file.

Try relocating your project with short path address and then try to build the project.