# IntelliJ : Build Failed

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I magically encountered several errors at once as I opened my android project-

1. Cannot resolve symbol `'R'`
2. Casting `findViewById(R.id.buto)` to `Button` is redundant

NOTE : I didn't had a single error in any of my files last time i closed it.
Yes, I have seen several [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio) to this on StackOverflow.

*What I did* -:

1. Rebuilded Project again
2. I did => File> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
3. Gradle Sync with project Files (it completed successfully with no errors)
4. Restarted IntelliJ

I have repeated above steps 2-3 times but i am not able to solve the errors.

This is my build.gradle(app) file: [build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86oCf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and rebuild the project

Comment: try removing R import and reimport using ALT+Enter

Comment: I mentioned those in my question.... and i am also getting errors like Program execution  -----> Process 'command 'C:\Users\(Username)\Appdata\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: take a look at this - ( this is one of my file) https://ibb.co/bQ8SPG (R is highlighted in red and Button, EditText etc are not highlighted i mean they are in grey color instead of white and they have a grey underline)