# I have run an IONIC project with using my device as the emulator but I suddenly get this error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

```
:processDebugResources
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
 FAILED
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.013 secs
(node:10212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
(node:10212) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question,

please refer this link,

[Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0)