# Error while creating APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Error log:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Gleb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\preference-v7-25.3.0.aar\7221e6c26cf352756fb7daa96d62f9bb\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:27: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\Gleb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\preference-v7-25.3.0.aar\7221e6c26cf352756fb7daa96d62f9bb\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:53: warn: generated id 'android:id/summary' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\Gleb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\preference-v7-25.3.0.aar\7221e6c26cf352756fb7daa96d62f9bb\res\layout\preference_widget_seekbar.xml:45: warn: generated id 'android:id/title' for external package 'android'.
C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\app\ecommstoreapp\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code2\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3247: error: style attribute 'attr/colorError (aka com.hairzaza.androidecommerce.demo2:attr/colorError)' not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Gleb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\e8393c774407b75689a3e9a4ddbe299c\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\app\ecommstoreapp\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code2\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\app\ecommstoreapp\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code2\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\app\ecommstoreapp\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code2\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\app\ecommstoreapp\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code2\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\app\ecommstoreapp\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code2\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.hairzaza.androidecommerce\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\app\ecommstoreapp\codecanyon-20952416-android-ecommerce-universal-android-ecommerce-store-full-mobile-app-with-laravel-cms\Android App Source Code2\Android App Source Code\ecommerce\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow; please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ... also, take a look at the [StackOverflow markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and format your question for readability

Comment: Did you check this similar StackOverflow question [Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49171052/5180017)?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from here

```
  values.xml:3247: error: style attribute 'attr/colorError (aka com.hairzaza.androidecommerce.demo2:attr/colorError)' not found. error: failed linking references.
```

It looks like thier is the problem

Please post your question properly so that we can help you further