# error: failed linking references (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, webview

I m trying to build android app from my existing website and add Firebase push notifications to it but errors comes up

I have include following dependencies :-

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
```

*

```
build failed    4 s 52 ms
Run build   3 s 455 ms
Load build  6 ms
Configure build 483 ms
Calculate task graph    84 ms
Run tasks   2 s 874 ms
null    
The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.   
failed linking references.
```

========================================================================

```
 Android resource linking failed
        Output:  D:\Android project\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:7: error: resource androiD:\attr/colorError not found.
        D:\Android project\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:11: error: resource androiD:\attr/colorError not found.
        D:\Android project\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'androiD:\attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
        error: failed linking references.

        CommanD:\ C:\Users\vinay\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\2be7a99c705cfa30acfde73eea92e599\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
                C:\Users\vinay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
                --manifest\
                D:\Android project\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\resources\AndroidManifest.xml\
                -o\
                D:\Android project\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
                -R\
                @D:\Android project\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
                --auto-add-overlay\
                --java\
                D:\Android project\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
                --custom-package\
                com.example.app\
                -0\
                apk\
                --preferred-density\
                560dpi\
                --output-text-symbols\
                D:\Android project\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
                --no-version-vectors
        Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0)

Comment: my problem is different but thanks

Comment: try to update gradle version, compile version and/or all google-play-services / firebase libraries version.
In most of the cases Firebase gives such errors because of old versions

Comment: Your compile SDK is 25 - should be 28.