# Android resource linking failed error: style attribute 'attr/textColorError (aka com.app.kite:attr/textColorError)' not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to use the [following](https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview) library (version 2.0.1) in my project but as soon as I tried to add it to my gradle file and build the project I started getting this error.

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\me\androidProject\kite\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:8642: error: style attribute 'attr/textColorError (aka com.app.kite:attr/textColorError)' not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\355577d385562aabb3c69eea7f88a383\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\me\androidProject\kite\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\me\androidProject\kite\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\me\androidProject\kite\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\me\androidProject\kite\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        C:\Users\me\androidProject\kite\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.app.kite\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\me\androidProject\kite\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

I updated my support lib to `28.0.0` but that doesn't work. My compile and target sdk versions are `28` and `buildToolsVersion` is 28.0.3. This is the library dependency as in my gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.0.1'
```

Can someone help. Thanks!!

Comment: Invalidate your cache and restart your studio

Comment: @RishabhSaxena STill facing it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0)

Answer (score 12):

Use `colorError` instead of `textColorError`.

If the usages of `textColorError` are inside that library and you can't change it, you won't be able to update to `28.0.0` until that is fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: create a file under values folder named attr.xml if not already exits and add the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="foo">
<attr name="textColorError" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Step 2: Add the following lines in styles.xml

```
 <style name="foo">
    <item name="textColorError">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Step 3: Clean the project and rebuild.

Answer (score -1):

Try to,

1. **Clean** your project
2. **Invalidate cache and Restart**
3. Delete the **.gradle** folder in the project and **build** folder under app/build