# resource linking failed while using mapbox navigation api in android native module of flutter app

Tags: android, flutter-dependencies, mapbox-android

I have facing this issue when I add Mapbox navigation API to the android native android module of the flutter application. The same dependency works perfectly when I use it in a standalone android application.

implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.28.0'.

I also tried the solutions here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0) but it didn't help.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:358)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:355)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output:  /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1359: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1360: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: /Users/eapple/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/2107f273d27b6ff1ad9399c8dbc745b7/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/eapple/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.tripmate\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
Output:  /Users/eapple/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/bc1fd563202989b0de541f77c34a0b13/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

/Users/eapple/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-28.0.0.aar/b3cdc6a0b01d6dfc0f67a7f905b97a4e/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/Users/eapple/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-28.0.0.aar/b3cdc6a0b01d6dfc0f67a7f905b97a4e/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

error: failed linking references.
Command: /Users/eapple/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/2107f273d27b6ff1ad9399c8dbc745b7/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/eapple/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.tripmate\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:527)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output:  /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1359: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1360: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: /Users/eapple/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/2107f273d27b6ff1ad9399c8dbc745b7/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/eapple/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.tripmate\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/eapple/AndroidStudioProjects/final_hybrid_tripmate/tripmate-flutter/build/app/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:177)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:823)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:525)
    ... 133 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by going to File>Project Structure in Android Studio and the setting the Compile SDK version and build tool version to the latest available. 
Here is a screenshot of my project structure settings. [image: project settings screenshot]

Comment: Just to add WHY: the library's version was 28.0.0. That means it needs the matching compile SDK version 28. It is using resources that were only added in API 28.