# error: resource style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.example.myapplication:style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog) not found

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am new in Android and trying to develop hello application with android studio version 3.3.2. I am trying to create Default Navigation Activity project and its giving error like below during build.

```
Android resource linking failed
error: resource style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.example.myapplication:style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.example.myapplication:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
error: resource style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar (aka com.example.myapplication:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar) not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:401: error: style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:402: error: style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v21\values-v21.xml:8: error: style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v21\values-v21.xml:9: error: style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.
error: resource style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light (aka com.example.myapplication:style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light) not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:416: error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu (aka com.example.myapplication:style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu) not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:417: error: resource style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp (aka com.example.myapplication:style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp) not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:421: error: style attribute 'attr/windowMinWidthMajor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowMinWidthMajor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:422: error: style attribute 'attr/windowMinWidthMinor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowMinWidthMinor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:425: error: style attribute 'attr/windowFixedWidthMajor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowFixedWidthMajor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:426: error: style attribute 'attr/windowFixedWidthMinor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowFixedWidthMinor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:427: error: style attribute 'attr/windowFixedHeightMajor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowFixedHeightMajor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:428: error: style attribute 'attr/windowFixedHeightMinor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowFixedHeightMinor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:431: error: style attribute 'attr/windowMinWidthMajor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowMinWidthMajor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:432: error: style attribute 'attr/windowMinWidthMinor (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/windowMinWidthMinor)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:438: error: style attribute 'attr/actionBarPopupTheme (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/actionBarPopupTheme)' not found.
F:\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:439: error: style attribute 'attr/actionBarWidgetTheme (aka com.example.myapplication:attr/actionBarWidgetTheme)' not found.
```

I have project gradle file like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I am able to import and run another projects but this is giving me error like above.

Comment: could you have a look at this post and check if that could be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0

Comment: add your styles.xml code from res/values/styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7)`. Choose "AppCompat"
`Project-> properties->Android`. In the section library **Add** and **choose** "AppCompat"

and if above not works try one more option as below

First check if you are using Androidx then do as below

**Remove**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

**Add this**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
```

check in your `gradel.properties` this two lines are added, if not added then add this line

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

then **clean** and **Rebuild** project once

Answer (score 1):

AppCompat is a library project. You need to reference the library project in your android project

1. **Include Google's Maven repository in your project's build.gradle file**

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
            If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
            instead use:
           maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
           }
       }
   }
2. For each module in which you want to use a Support Library, add the library in the dependencies block of the module's build.gradle file. For example, to add the v7 core-utils library, add the following:

**implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"**