# Resources task gives error and appcompat-v7 is not loaded

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

After reopening the existing project. Android Studio give me the error above :

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processMatriksiqPilotDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4136: error: resource anim/abc_popup_enter (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_popup_enter) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4137: error: resource anim/abc_popup_exit (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_popup_exit) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4140: error: resource anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4141: error: resource anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4144: error: resource anim/abc_tooltip_enter (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_tooltip_enter) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4145: error: resource anim/abc_tooltip_exit (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_tooltip_exit) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4308: error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4311: error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_text_material (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_btn_colored_text_material) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4365: error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4417: error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4449: error: resource color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4452: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_primary_text_material_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4453: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_light (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_primary_text_material_light) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4454: error: resource color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4455: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4456: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4457: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4458: error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4459: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark) not found.
  C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4460: error: resource color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light) not found.

  Command: C:\Users\Matriks\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\71100e6b9d2bf9a21b7e945e51b741cd\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Matriks\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\matriksiqPilotDebug\processMatriksiqPilotDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\matriksiqPilotDebug\processMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\out\resources-matriksiqPilotDebug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-matriksiqPilotDebug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\matriksiqPilotDebug\processMatriksiqPilotDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.matriksdata.mobileiq\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\Matriks\Desktop\Projects\arda\app\build\intermediates\symbols\matriksiqPilot\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Matriks\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\6979c0ccf4af5e928f6107e46b546a2b\res\values\values.xml:1467:5-1470:13: AAPT: error: resource anim/abc_popup_enter (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_popup_enter) not found.

  ...and goes on
```

It can not found values that comes from appcompat-v7.

I have a line

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

but there is no v7 jar in external libraries part. So i think my problem is, my android studio can not load v7 to project.

Any idea ? Thanks

**EDIT**

Full Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: '../preprocessor.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.15"

//        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
    }


    signingConfigs {
        release {
            def storeFilePath = System.properties['user.home'] + "\\.gradle\\${mtxStoreFile}"
            println(storeFilePath)
            storeFile file(storeFilePath)
            storePassword "${mtxStorePassword}"
            keyAlias "${mtxKeyAlias}"
            keyPassword "${mtxKeyPassword}"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting: "true"]

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting: "false"]

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            //debug version suffix
            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions "company", "environment"
    productFlavors {

        pilot {
            dimension "environment"
        }

        internal {
            dimension "environment"
        }

        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "com.matriks.internal.mtxui:rateview-mtx-ui:$rateview_view_version"

    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"

    //SUPPORTS
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'

    //MTXs
    implementation "com.matriks.internal.news:news-library:$news_lib_version"
    implementation "com.matriks.internal.ecocalendar:ecoCalendar-library:$ecalendar_version"
    implementation "com.matriks.internal.notification-lib:notificationlibrary:$notification_version"
    implementation ("com.matriks.internal.mtxlogpages:mtxlogpages-library:$logpages_library") {
        exclude group: 'com.matriks.internal.uiframework', module: 'uiframework-library'
    }

    if(use_level_analysis){
        println("LevelAnalysis Local copy used")

        implementation files(devDir + '/level-analysis-library-debug.aar')
    }
    else{
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.level-analysis:level-analysis-library:$level_analysis"
    }

    if(use_swap_local){

        println("Swap Local copy used")

        implementation files(devDir + '/swap-analysis-library-debug.aar')

    }else{

        implementation "com.matriks.internal.swap-analysis:swap-analysis-library:$mtx_swap_lib_version"
    }

    implementation "com.matriks.internal.mtxalarm:alarm-library:$alarm_version"

    implementation("com.matriks.internal.mtxcharts:mtxcharts-library:$mtxcharts_version") {
        exclude group: 'com.matriks.internal.uiframework', module: 'uiframework-library'
    }

    implementation("com.matriks.internal.capital-increase:capital-increase-library:$capital_increase_version") {
        exclude group: 'com.matriks.internal.uiframework', module: 'uiframework-library'
    }

    if (use_companycard_local) {

        println("Company Card Local copy used")

        implementation files(devDir + '/company-card-library-debug.aar')

    } else {

        implementation "com.matriks.internal.companycard:company-card-library:$company_card_library"
    }

    if (use_mtx_license_local) {

        println("MTX License Local copy used")

        implementation files(devDir + '/mtxlicense-library-debug.aar')

    } else {

        implementation("com.matriks.internal.mtxlicense:mtxlicense-library:$mtxlicense_version") {
            exclude group: 'com.matriks.internal.uiframework', module: 'uiframework-library'
        }
    }


    implementation "com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:$pdf_viewer_version"
    if (use_framework_local) {
        println("Framework Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/framework-library-debug.aar')
        implementation files(devDir + '/framework-database.jar')

        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$converter_gson_version"
        implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$logging_interceptor_version"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$converter_scalars_version"

        implementation "org.greenrobot:eventbus:$eventbus_version"
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.framework:framework-library:$framework_version"
    }
    if (use_ui_framework_local) {
        println("UI Framework Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/uiframework-library-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.uiframework:uiframework-library:$ui_framework_version"
    }

    if (use_mtx_symbol_detail_local) {
        println("Symbol Detail Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/mtx-symbol-detail-debug.aar')

        implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.1'
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.detail:mtx-symbol-detail:$mtx_symbol_detail_version"
    }

    if (use_bi_local) {
        println("BI Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/mtxbussinessinteractions-library-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.mtxbussinessinteractions:mtxbussinessinteractions-library:$bi_version"
    }
    if (use_tradeui_local) {
        println("tradeui Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/mtxtradeui-library-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation("com.matriks.internal.mtxtradeui:mtxtradeui-library:$tradeui_version") {
            exclude group: 'com.matriks.internal.uiframework', module: 'uiframework-library'
        }
    }
    if (use_datatable_local) {
        println("datatable Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/mtx-datatable-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.datatable:mtx-datatable:$data_table_version"
    }
    if (use_market_table_local) {
        println("marketstable local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/mtxmarketstable-library-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.mtxmarketstable:mtxmarketstable-library:$mtx_table_version"
    }

    if (use_calculator_local) {
        println("calculator Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/warrantcalculator-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation("com.matriks.internal.warrantcalculator:warrantcalculator:$w_calculator_version") {
            exclude group: 'com.matriks.internal.uiframework', module: 'uiframework-library'
        }

    }
    if (use_bridge_local) {
        println("Bridge Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/bridge-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.mtxwebconnection:bridge:$bridge_version"
    }

    if (use_symbol_selection_local) {
        println("Symbol Selection Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/symbol-selection-library-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation("com.matriks.internal.symbolselection:symbol-selection-library:$symbol_selection_lib_version") {
            exclude group: 'com.matriks.internal.uiframework', module: 'uiframework-library'
        }
    }

    if (use_dumrul_local) {
        println("Dumrul Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/dumrul-client-debug.aar')

        implementation "org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:$paho_client_version"
        implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:$protobuf_version"

    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.dumrul:dumrul-client:$dumrul_version"
    }

    if (use_cms_local) {
        println("CMS Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/cms-library-debug.aar')

    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.cms:cms-library:$cms_lib_version"
    }

    if (use_cms_ui_local) {
        println("CMS UI Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/cms-ui-library-debug.aar')

    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.cms-ui:cms-ui-library:$cms_ui_version"
    }
    if (use_akd_local) {
        println("AKD Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/akd-library-debug.aar')

    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.akd:akd-library:$akd_version"
    }

    if (use_return_comp_local) {
        println("Return Comparison Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/return-comparison-lib-debug.aar')

    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.returncomparisonlib:return-comparison-lib:$return_comparison_version"
    }

    if (use_mtx_depth_local) {
        println("Depth Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/depth-library-debug.aar')

    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.depth:depth-library:$depth_version"
    }

    if (use_twitter_local) {
        println("Twitter Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/mtxtwitterview-library-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.mtxtwitterview:mtxtwitterview-library:$twitter_lib_version"
    }

    if (use_converter_local) {
        println("Currency converter Local copy used")
        implementation files(devDir + '/currencyconverter-library-debug.aar')
    } else {
        implementation "com.matriks.internal.currencyconverter:currencyconverter-library:$currency_converter_version"
    }

    //ROOM
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$arch_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$arch_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$arch_version"

    //DAGGER
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    // Chrome Custom Tabs
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$support_version"

    //CRASHLYTICS
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //FIREBASE
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_messaging_version"

    //BUTTER KNIFE
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor "com.matriks.internal.framework:framework-dbprocessor:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    //PageIndicatorView - https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.1'
}

// EN ALTTA OLMALI
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And I have dependencies.gradle for boolean and string values for gradle variables but i think this file is not needed,

Comment: can you post your gradle?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: check this file does exist in your project "error: resource anim/abc_popup_enter (aka com.matriksdata.mobileiq:anim/abc_popup_enter) not found."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0)

Comment: @Zoe this is not same thing and solution is different

Answer (score 2):

After deleting all cache files under

C:\Users\Matriks.gradle\caches

everything works fine=)