# Unable to run build / run any project in android studio. Error : Process unexpectedly exit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have upgraded Android Studio to 3.4.1 and Gradle 5.1.1. Showing error: "Process unexpectedly exits",  while run /builds project.

How to resolve this?

1. I tried Clean Projec-> Rebuild Project
2. Uninstalled complete Android Studio and then Re-installed
3. Followed Some Stack Overflow suggestion as well.

Nothing worked

```
Error: Process unexpectedly exit.

org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failure.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 8 exceptions were raised by workers:

com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: Failed to start AAPT2 process.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Process unexpectedly exit.
```

[image: Error screen 1]

[image: Details Erroe 1]
[image]

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0)

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: No I didn't.
What I did is, downgraded the Gradle version to 3.2.0.

Comment: Refer to answer posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61167879/6322049