# Keep facing Process unexpectedly exit in Android Studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

After an update of `Java` facing an issue of **Process unexpectedly exit** while creating the build for Android. I was using `Android Studio 3.3.0` and updated it also into **3.4.1** also to see any update but there is no change. Currently I'm using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

could not run my app. When I try to run the error shows : **Process unexpectedly exit.**

I have tried with downgrading the version of `gradle` from `3.4.1` to `3.1.4` but it also din't work. And it gives a new error **Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741502**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your build gradle version to 3.1.4 to solve this

Comment: It gives new error for existing project **Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741502**

Comment: If you install Android 3.3+ go with gradle as follows:
    
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar its very lower version, it tells `Could not find method implementation() for arguments`

Comment: can you clean and rebuild your project...?

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar Have done many times.

Comment: Use the gradle build tool version 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your problem, just try to delete `.iml` file of your existing project from the directory and then rebuild the project again. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your studio seems to be messed up so you should try resetting it by going to c/users/documents and delete these three folders .android,.androidstudio3.4,.gradle after deleting restart your studio and see if this fixes it

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up because of latest version of AAPT library.
Just add below code in your Project gradle file under allprojects section.

```
 configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem of getting **Process unexpectedly exit error** usually occurs if you done a Android Studio upgrade or fresh install of android studio while without 'cleaning' traces of older versions of Android Studio. The reason could be that when you have multiple older versions of **Android Studio residue files** there is some conflict because of older version of .Android, .gradle, .cache  and android sdk files/folders. I tried everything from clearing cashe, invalidating and restarting t downgrading gradle to different versions but nothing worked.

Next I decided to uninstall Android Studio 3.6.2 and do fresh install Android Studio 3.6.2 which is latest version as of 12th April 2020 () but that do did not remove the **Process unexpectedly exit** and even creating a new Hello World projectI would get the Process unexpectedly exit error .

in my 3rd try I again uninstalled Android Studio 3.6.2, then went to %userprofiles% and deleted the .Android, .gradle, .cache and delete android sdk folders.  Reinstalled
Android Studio 3.6.2 and the **Process unexpectedly exit** error was resolved. I have shared detailed steps so that you do not waste time in doing what I did for couple of days. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade the version of **gradle** from
 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'` 
to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

Comment: I was using the same version before to update the `Android Studio`

Comment: Downgrading causes incompatibility with AS/Gradle.