# Android Studio build error logs not shown correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a simple project and I remove some color resources from my file.

**Expectations:**

I build the project and it should fail. In the `Build Output` I should have the logs where it shows me the files where build fails. (Because the color resources are missing)

**Reality (Android Studio 3.4.2):**

I build the project and it fails. In the `Build Output` I see:

```
Android resource linking failed...
```

I navigate through all the failed tasks and none of them shows the proper logs.
Android Studio used to have this working properly. Does any one know any settings that maybe can fix what the Build Output shows?

I know that if I `Analyze > Inspect code` I can see the proper list of files where there are errors. But this takes time. I also know that running the build task in terminal it shows the files where there are errors. I want to have it like it used to be before.

I know that someone at Android Studio had one job and he didn't do it right but here I am for your help.

Comment: check this if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in `Android Studio 3.5`

Just in case:
Be aware of this issue: [Android studio 3.5 refactor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591080/android-studio-3-5-refactor-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try: **Build -> Clean Project**
That cleans the gradle file

Alternatively: **File->Invalidate Caches / Restart**
Then **Sync Project** with gradle files

Give these a go and see if it changes anything. It should start giving error for resource file.