# when run my project show this massage "Android resource linking failed"

Tags: android

when run my project show this massage

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:25: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:26: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:28: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.

org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:29)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:174)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.

C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.

C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:25: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.

C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:26: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.

C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:28: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.

C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:38: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.

    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:808)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.run(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:669)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:262)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:25: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:26: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:28: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.
C:\Users\prakash khadka\Desktop\Video downloader for FB\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest>.

    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:191)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:858)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$AaptSplitInvoker.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:797)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: You have misplaced elements in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

> AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: unexpected element  found in

The error might be in the manifest file, post your manifest file if you didn't find. And also try to Clean and Rebuild the Project.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Syntax Error exist in xml file that's while linking failed.

here you can visit this link too
[Error - Android resource linking failed (AAPT2 27.0.3 Daemon #0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171052/error-android-resource-linking-failed-aapt2-27-0-3-daemon-0)