# New kotlin files in old java project - 'Unresolved reference' R

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, kotlin

Have an already existing java project. Trying to add new kotlin files to it. AndroidStudio 3.1 complains that R is an "Unresolved reference".

I can manually import R and it builds without error. But why is R not automatically imported as always?

Edit-
clean&build or restarting AS didnot help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183656/4778343

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @StefanGolubović. But clean->build or restarting AS didnot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS Preferences, under General -> Auto Import, i enabled the following. [image]

This imports R automatically now.

Comment: Where is that option in Android Studio?.

Comment: @glisu See Preferences -> Editor -> General > Auto Import -> Java

Answer (score 1):

See imports inside kotlin file. Package names might be from your old project, that won't allow you to use R.
Delete them, and reimport

Comment: No package name changes though. other imports are good. Just R is not imported at all.

Comment: do you copy paste, or import via ide?

Comment: Does R get automatically imported for you on AS 3.1 and kotlin?

Comment: please explain how u import kotlin files? I just copy paste and correct the imports, when needed

Comment: I import with autoimport functionality

Comment: check for errors inside files. AS won't build until therent any, and until you have a successful build R isnt avialible

Comment: i can import R manually and still successfully build. My question was why doesn't it import R automatically like it does for other imports. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Just import your main package R in your kotlin file where you got this error.

Like:

```
import com.example.activities.R
```