# R file is missing?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-developer-api

R file is missing in android. I had tried many solutions like clean project, rebuild project, sync Gradle but couldn't fix it.

Comment: are you able to run the app? Iam asking because, sometimes android studio simply complains but actually the app can be executed

Comment: when you have a successful build, you have R in your project. also check package names

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio/49465461#49465461

Comment: Android Studio won't build R file because of errors in one/many resource files, for instance unclosed tags. Check the xml files you modified last

Answer (score 1):

Check for all your XML files for any errors. Once error is resolved, try clean and then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Slide out the Build Variants Tab and make sure you are on the expected build variant.  If you are missing layout files in a certain build variant, then Android Studio will fail to build and the generated R class is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we should try to have internet while we are coding because IDE has to load many resources at this time.
Secondly In that specific case I was loading a resource of type (v24).
Third Resource name was in capital latter.
Thats why it wasn't working properly.