# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol 'raw'

Tags: java, android-studio

I've a resource directory called "raw" in the "res" folder, but still can't access it through my code. The problem occurs when trying to declare the MediaPlayer variable.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer pSong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pSong = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.rando);


        Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio?rq=1 Have you looked here?

Comment: @Michel_T. Cleaning the build solved the problem. I'm new to Android Studio. Care to tell me what this does? Also, everytime I make a new project I have to change: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' to alpha1 (instad of alpha3). Why is this and can I premanently set it to alpha1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Android Studio 3.6+:

Click on `Build` -> `Rebuild Project` and then click `File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

### Android Studio 3.5 and earlier:

Click on `Build` -> `Rebuild Project` and then click `Tools` -> `Android` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: In new version "Sync Project with Gradle Files" is under Files , not Tools. Secondly it did not work for me. Restarting Android Studio fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 14):

Rebuilding and Syncing did not work for me. Had to restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 6):

1. Build then Clean >> didn't solve
2. Removing Build folder from app level >> didn't solve
3. Removing Build folder from Project level >> didn't solve
4. Synch project with Gradle >> didn't solve

***Finally solved by restarting android studio***

Answer (score 2):

Hitting **Build -> Clean Project** solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File** -> **Re-import Gradle Project**
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In the new version, Just after writing the code, run code, it'll run adjusting the error itself.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 4+:
Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
this will let android studio to index the raw files.

Answer (score 0):

I put music file in the raw folder in type ".m4a" and then error gone.

Answer (score 0):

Use Your Package name In front of R for Example:

```
com.example.app.R.raw.yourFile
```