# Categories' is incompatible with attribute android:iconTint (attr) color

Tags: android

i created 2 fragment category and ranked but it says Cannot resolve 'R'

i did clean project and rebuilt project but it doesnt work. What can i do?

This are my codes;

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
 @NullableViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    myFragment= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ranking,container,false);
    return myFragment;
}
```

Here is same error R is colored by red! :(

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragment= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category,container,false);
    return myFragment;
}
```

Comment: Try to re import you R.class in your activity by deleting previos import

Comment: unfortunately ... :(

Comment: Check your xml files, something wrong. look this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28975079/6352712

Comment: maby fragment_category.xml became not valid

Comment: it says ; error: 'Categories' is incompatible with attribute android:iconTint (attr) color.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: 'Categories' is incompatible with attribute android:iconTint (attr) color., sources=[C:\Users\Cagri\Desktop\KpssGenelKltrTesti\app\src\main\res\menu\bottom_menu.xml:4], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: Edit your question to include bottom_menu.xml