# Cannot resolve symbol R and nothing is working?

Tags: java, android

So, I was working on a project in Android Studio, everything was going well until I had to sync my project and my R went red and now it doesn't recognize any of my layouts  or anything of the sort...
I tried cleaning, rebuilding and Clean Caches - it's not working.

Comment: Terminal -> `./gradlew clean build`. Do any errors show up? Failing to resolve `R` normally means a previous build has failed.

Comment: Maybe you have an issue in your xml files. Check if they contain no errors

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches/  Restart has helped me with similar issues in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

- first of all check your `XML` file where you are working now 
  maybe there is some problem in your XML file
- after go to in your android studio and click `file` menu in dropdown select `invalidate cache/restart`

Answer (score -1):

**Try to below steps I hope it will help you.**

Go  to the projet and select option sync with gradle file's.

or once you have to try restart the android studio.