# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' - nothing fixes it

Tags: android, android-studio

Every once in a while I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`, on a random project, and nothing seems to fix that.
Of course I tried the following procedure: [“cannot resolve symbol R” in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio). But even invalidating caches or rebuilding the project didn't work.

Any other causes for this? And how to fix that?

Comment: update your sdk manager

Comment: might be a problem in one of your layout files (e.g. typos like textView instead of TextView, or custom Views with the wrong package name) . the IDE  will fail to generate the R files if any of the resources files have a problem. you can go check your latest changes by reviewing  the Local History in your RES folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

1. File -> Synch Project with Gradle Files
2. Build -> Clean Project
3. Build -> Rebuild Project
4. Gradle from the right pane -> MyAppName -> :app -> Tasks -> build -> clean
   [image]
5. Left Project Navigation pane (Android view) -> build.grade (Module:app) -> Update the version of appcompat & design support dependencies to the recent version by ALT + ENTER on each of them
6. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
7. Upgrade to the latest android studio

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error occurs when you have some error in your *layout or any other resource file*.

- Just recall if you have changed any of the resource file (layout, strings, color etc). And see if you find error in any of these file.
- You can also check your manifest file and see if it gives you any error.
- Clean your project, rebuild, restart Android Studio and check again.

Comment: None of the resources files gives me an error. The manifest is also clean. Not sure what to do now

Comment: I found out the problem, I am using Firebase and it automatically added the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, now I removed it and it works. But won't that damage any other part of the code that I yet to know?

Comment: When using firebase with `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, you must add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` in the gradle file at the project root, otherwise, you get other error with gradle. See the firebase configuration for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Answer (score 0):

Check `layout_width` and `layout_height` on your various components. When I had a number as opposed to `match_constraint` or `wrap_content`, I failed to add "*dp*" afterwards, and the number wasn't compatible with the dimension. Stupid mistake, but adding *dp* fixed the R problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me when I encountered this error was looking in the gradle.build file of the component in question. For instance, when working on an app for Amazon Fire TV using their development kit at

An error I encountered here

> import com.amazon.dataloader.R not found

was solved when I looked in the gradle.build file of the DataLoader component and changed

```
namespace "com.amazon.dataloader"
namespace "com.amazon.dataloader.test"
```

to

```
namespace "com.amazon.dataloader"
testNamespace "com.amazon.dataloader.test"
```

I then cleaned my project, invalidated my cache, rebuilt the project, and that solved the error.