# Not able to find the R file in Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I am creating an Android app and while extracting the String resources for all the Strings, I am getting an error.

So I thought about it and figured out that we are getting the String by accessing the `R` file and when I checked `app > build > generated > source >`, the `R` file was missing. I also have checked the `string.xml` file and the String is also getting created over there, hence I thought the issue is with the `R` file.

For example, while converting the String `Date of birth`:

```
getString(R.string.dob);
```

It says that `dob` symbol is not resolvable even though I extracted its (Date of Birth) String resource and had the resource named to `dob`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Comment: The op of that question is not able to find R .. in my case i'm not able to find R as well as the string resource by which i'm accessing it . Like in the above line my question,  'dob' is not resolvable.however , i'll try it . thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Android Studio the following works:

Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
It worked for me.

Comment: The gradle files were synced and the project was built successfully....