# Error when updating to Gradle 3.3.2 in Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If I update Gradle by changing

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.x.x'
}
```

from version **3.2.1** to version **3.3.2** I get the `Cannot resolve symbol R` error on all activities **but** the project actually builds without errors. Don't know what might be causing this. I realized on the Android view of the project files, under `app/generatedJava/` there are many packages with version **3.2.1**, but when updated none of them are there, except for a `BuildConfig.java` class under `my.app.package`.

I've already tried all the **Build -> Clean**, **Build -> Rebuild**, **File -> Invalidate caches**, **File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files**, etc. methods which would solve the problem and still not finding the R class.

With version **3.2.1** this doesn't happen though.

Comment: most probably network issue as not downloaded gradle

Comment: try deleting the generated R.java file and again clean,bulid and rebuild

Comment: @Gaston Barbero have you try with new version 3.3.2? and try again Invalidate caches

Comment: @primo There is no generated R.java file. That's the issue.

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos That's actually what I'm trying. When I update the project is when I get the error.

Comment: @Basi But how come it build successfully then?

Comment: Try Updating The Gradle..

Comment: ok try file -> sync project with gradle files!

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos already tried and nothing

Comment: @VivekMakwana That's what I'm doing. And that's when I get the error.

Comment: Is There any kind of network issue?? Because i just upgraded it to 3.3.2 , its working fine..

Comment: Have You updated to Android Studio 3.3.2

Comment: @VivekMakwana That actually fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vivek stated in the comments, the solution is to upgrade Android Studio as well. I upgraded to version [`3.3`](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3-3-0) and it finally solved the problem for me.