# Android layout ids not recognised

Tags: android

I'm trying to get Android studio to recognise IDs of various views etc. in my layout.xml file. When I was inputting the code in the xml, everything seemed OK, but when I revisited my code today, the ids in the layout file were in red saying "cannot resolve symbol."

When I tried to access the view (eg using "view.findViewById(R.id.splo)"), it says it cannot resolve the symbol (in this case "splo").

I'm not doing anything radical, for instance this is how I define splo in my layout xml:

```
        <TextView android:id="@+id/splo" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
```

Doing some digging, I found that I don't have a res/values/id.xml file - and looking further I don't have anything below app/build/generated/source, so no R.java file either.

I've looked at some people's requests for help - one was very similar to mine (["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)) but the solutions offered don't help.

I've done multiple invalidate cache and restart, with or without Build->clean project and nothing works, and the IDs are still not recognised. Can anyone help?

Comment: delete .idea file and then apply invalidate cache and restart again

Comment: Did you import the correct `R`? Every library has one and code completion takes its time to put the correct one to the top of the suggestion list.

Comment: Hi Zafer, that did the trick, thank you! Sorry for this late reply, I have been in hospital.

Answer (score 2):

Well there might be potential errors in the package name when you are building your application.

> **Since you mentioned, you already tried rebuilding and cleaning the project, we won't waste time doing that again!**

---

### What I want you to do now is:

1. Open your **AndroidMainfest.xml file**
2. Scroll to the top and check is the **package** name is correct
3. If its correct then go to the **Activity** definitions in the **manifest** and check:

   - If the **package** name in these lines **[android:name="`YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`.`YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME`"]** is correctly assigned
   - If you see the above line is in this format **[android:name=".`YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME`]"**, then bring it in the above format **by adding the package name before the dot**.
   - Now **clean** and **rebuild** your project.

---

> The problem should be solved and if not my request is that **please
>   Upload your AndroidManifest.xml** file and your **package
>   information** so that I can have a better look at the issue

Comment: Hi, Very sorry for this late reply. I looked at the xml file and it looked OK, but I managed to find the correct solution thanks to @Zafer Celaloglu

Comment: Deleting the .idea file, hmm I see. Then it was probably the issue with the IDE. Anyways its good you solved the issue but if possible check out why that folder got the issue and report it in the Android Studio so that if the IDE has got some bugs, they can fix it.