# How to find symbol variable from R.id when I can't design my layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting 6 errors of type 'cannot find symbol'
for R. variables from those lines:

```
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ntitle, title);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ntext, text);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright, R.drawable.crow2);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotleft, R.drawable.crow);
```

I am trying to make an app with notification options, I thought that R.id stuff is supposed to link with id of components from layout. Problem is I can't open my layout for some reason, only options I have is 'Text' and 'Merged Manifest' there's no 'Design'.

Entire code just in case:

```
package com.example.student.myapplication;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


static int clickCounter = 0;

private void showNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder builder)
{
    NotificationManager nNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService (NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nNotifyMgr.notify(clickCounter, builder.build());

}

private NotificationCompat.Builder getBuilder(String title, String text){
    return (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text);

}

public void showBasicNotification(View view)
{
    showNotification(getBuilder("basic notification", totalClicks()));
}

public void showCustomNotification(View view)
{
    String title = "custom.notification";
    String text = totalClicks();
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customnotification);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ntitle, title);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ntext, text);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright, R.drawable.crow2);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotleft, R.drawable.crow);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = getBuilder(title, text);

        builder.setContent(remoteViews);
        showNotification(builder);





}

private String totalClicks()
{
    return "total clicks on projekt2 so far: " + ++clickCounter;
}
```

}

Gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.student.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: remoteview.findViewById(R.id.....) to find your views from custom layout

Comment: Probably your **application id** is different than your **activity package** In that case you have to  `import` **R**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Wini do you mean this? <module external.linked.project.id="MyApplication"

Comment: Ops, your old comment is gone, I was refering to project id that you asked.

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added it to main post

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add R.java class. Please add import section.

```
import  com.example.student.myapplication.R;//<yourPackageName>.R;
```

Comment: Still the same :(