# Do I have to declare "R" to use it in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, layout, layout-inflater

I am not sure why this line is wrong below. The "R" is being underlined in red.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(android.support.v4.R.layout.user_item, viewGroup, false);
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'R'
```

Is this the correct version or do I have to change something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

write it as usual R.layout.user_item then place the cursor on red color R and press ALT+Enter this list will appear, click on import it will do the job.

and if it does not work then go to the project folder

[image]

delete these two Gradle files.

[image]

Click on this sync project with Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the project and cleaning it. That usually fixes it. Also try syncing project with Gradle files. It's the little elephant at the top right.

Comment: It still isn't working. It says Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio

Look at this

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the `user_item` layout yourself, you should just use `R` instead of `android.support.v4.R`.

Comment: I did that but R is still in the red.

Comment: Do you only have the problem in that particular spot ? I guess youre using some other resources as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's only in this spot